# SpringBoot has an issue creating bean with MongoDB Java ClassFile Version

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I've looked at countless articles to try to figure out the issue. The only debug statement that I think appears to be the problem is the Java ClassFile Version 61.0, but I'm not sure why that would be the case. Here's the code below.

Structure:

```
testApp.app
testApp.app.model
testApp.app.repository
testApp.app.resource
```

Code:

TestAppApplication.java

```
package com.testApp.app;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class TestAppApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestAppApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Data.java

```
package com.testApp.app.model;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

@Document(collection = "Data")
public class Data {

    @Id
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String description;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Data [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", description=" + description + "]";
    }


}
```

DataRepository.java

```
package com.testApp.app.repository;

import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import com.testApp.app.model.Data;

@Repository
public interface DataRepository extends MongoRepository<Data, Integer> {

}
```

DataController.java

```
package com.testApp.app.resource;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import com.testApp.app.model.Data;
import com.testApp.app.repository.DataRepository;

@RestController
public class DataController {

    @Autowired
    private DataRepository dataRepository;

    @PostMapping("/addData")
    public String savaData(@RequestBody Data data) {
        dataRepository.save(data);
        return "Added book with id: " + data.getId();
    }

    @GetMapping("/findAllData")
    public List<Data> getAllData() {
        return dataRepository.findAll();
    }

    @GetMapping("/findAllData/{id}")
    public Optional<Data> getData(@PathVariable int id) {
        return dataRepository.findById(id);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/deleteData/{id}")
    public String deleteData(@PathVariable int id) {
        dataRepository.deleteById(id);
        return "Book deleted with id: " + id;
    }
}
```

application.properties

```
spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.database=TestApp
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.testApp</groupId>
    <artifactId>TestApp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>TestApp</name>
    <description>TestApp Project with SpringBoot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Debug log

```
Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dataController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'dataRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataRepository' defined in com.checkr.app.repository.DataRepository defined in @EnableMongoRepositories declared on MongoRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableMongoRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mongoTemplate' while setting bean property 'mongoOperations'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDatabaseFactoryDependentConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'mongoTemplate' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoDatabaseFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDatabaseFactoryConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'mongoDatabaseFactory' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mongo' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/mongo/MongoAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'mongo' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoClientSettings' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/mongo/MongoAutoConfiguration$MongoClientSettingsConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings]: Factory method 'mongoClientSettings' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/bson/codecs/record/RecordCodecProvider has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 60.0
```

Comment: `java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/bson/codecs/record/RecordCodecProvider has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 60.0`